# Executing a stored procedure over ODBC

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, odbc, unixodbc

I have an application that allows the user to enter an SQL string with a placeholder for certain values my application produces. The application will the replace the placeholders with values and execute the SQL string through various database backends.

For the ODBC backend, I call SQLExecDirect() on the SQL strin which works nicely on regular queries, but fails for stored procedures with parameters.

Is there a simple way to extend this mechanism to support stored procedures ? A certain way how the SQL must be written ?

The only thing I can think of right now is to start parsing the SQL string and call SQLBindParameter() n times if it conatains a "call". But parsing SQL is tricky.

Any ideas ?

Working SQL example: SELECT columnA from foo where columnB = '%placeholder'

Non-working SQL: CALL StoredFoo('%placeholder')

Comment: Sounds like a terrible application.. no offense.. I would recommend creating a specific interface for stored procedures, if this is required functionality.  How do you trust your users to write good, non-destructive queries?

Comment: The application is installed on the PC of the user and as part of the configuration process, he can put the SQL statements where to save values into his config file. So there is no security concern other than he may accidently overwrite his own data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to call stored procedures (ODBC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216572%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

> To run a procedure as an RPC
>
> 1. Construct a SQL statement that uses the ODBC CALL escape sequence.
>      The statement uses parameter markers
>      for each input, input/output, and
>      output parameter, and for the
>      procedure return value (if any):
>
>    `{? = CALL procname (?,?)}`
> 2. Call SQLBindParameter for each input, input/output, and output
>      parameter, and for the procedure
>      return value (if any).
> 3. Execute the statement with `SQLExecDirect`.

Otherwise you need to execute the procedure as an ordinary batch (not an RPC call), ie. you need to run the batch:

```
EXEC procname @param1, @param2, @param3...;
```